# Many (thousands) distinct users in BigQuery with distinct permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am evaluating BigQuery as a solution for a large scale deployment where I would need thousands of distinct users with distinct permissions (on specific datasets). Is this something that is possible in any way on Google Cloud? It appears there are quotas on both Users and Service Accounts, as well as Projects. I don't see any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: The maximum number of IAM members per project is 1,500. https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas

Answer (score 0):

In GCP you do not grant permissions to the user, instead you grant them roles. A role is a collection of permissions [1].  You can check here [2]  the different types of roles and in [3] is the documentation on how to create a custom role.  Also, you can grant permissions by granting roles to a user, a group or a service account. Here [4] is how you can grant the roles to the users.  Additionally, you can also control the access to the datasets [5]  .
Can you give more information about “ the quotas on both Users and Service Accounts”? I did not understand you quite well.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#roles

[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

[3] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles

[4]https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access

[5] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls